# I keep getting Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getMemos()", data="0x", errorArgs=null

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I keep getting this error whenever I try to run this block of code below:

Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getMemos()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (interface.ts:427:1)
at Contract. (index.ts:400:1)
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)

```
const getMemos = async () => {
            try {
              const { ethereum } = window;

              if (ethereum) {
                const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
                const signer = provider.getSigner();
                const coffeeTip = new ethers.Contract(
                  contractAddress,
                  contractABI,
                  signer
                );
                
                console.log("fetching memos from the blockchain..");
                const memos = await coffeeTip.getMemos();
                console.log("fetched!");
                setMemos(memos);
              } else {
                console.log("Metamask is not connected");
              }
              
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          };
```

Comment: It is usually a problem executing the function in the contract. Some checks you have to do: is it connected to the right network?, is the contract address correct?, is the abi for the contract?, is the contract correctly initialized? Also check the function for possible error conditions, reading from an uninitialized variable, writing without allocating memory, etc.